# One person on team not able to save to desktop, getting Path not found

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Excel VB script, whereas once you hit a button it saves as a PDF to the desktop. But one person on the team, is getting a Path not found error.
We are all on a domain for work

Here is the script, any advice welcome

```
'*** Automatically Creates and Saves PDF to Desktop ***
    Sheets("cA Quote").Select
    ChDir Environ("HOMEPATH") & "\Desktop"
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=Environ("HOMEPATH") & "\Desktop\" & UCase([C9]) & " cA Quote " & sFileSaveDate & ".pdf", Quality:= _
            xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
```

[image]

Comment: How about downloads folder?

Comment: You may have to  prepend %HOMEPATH% with %HOMEDRIVE%

Comment: If you pass the full path there's no need for the `ChDir`.  As dbmitch suggests `Environ("HOMEDRIVE") & Environ("HOMEPATH")` seems to be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try a different method of dynamically getting the desktop path. This one asks the shell for the path:

```
Public Function DesktopPath() As String
    With CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        GetDesktop = .SpecialFolders("Desktop") & "\"
    End With
End Function
```

You don't need the select or the `ChDir` so your code would then look like this:

```
'*** Automatically Creates and Saves PDF to Desktop ***
    Sheets("cA Quote").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=DesktopPath & UCase([C9]) & " cA Quote " & sFileSaveDate & ".pdf", _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _ 
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=True
```

Answer (score 1):

For me easiest way to save someting on user's desktop is to use Environ("UserProfile") & "\Desktop" which returns the full path. You don't need the ChDir in this case.

```
'*** Automatically Creates and Saves PDF to Desktop ***
Sheets("cA Quote").Select
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=Environ("UserProfile") & "\Desktop\" & UCase([C9]) & " cA Quote " & sFileSaveDate & ".pdf", Quality:= _
        xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
```